# Debug c++ dll in C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I have a .dll from c++ and I want to debug it in C#, but I don't know how to.

When I compiled the c++ project, Visual studio asked me to execute an ".exe".

I supposed that I had to create a project to execute the dll.

But I am lost, how could I debug it?

Answer (score 46):

If I understand you correctly, you want to debug a C++ coded DLL that you created, in a C# project that calls the DLL, which you also created?

I've done this before by going into your C# project properties, and under the Debug section, checking the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" check box. This should allow you to step into your C++ DLL.

Comment: Also, in Visual Studio 2012 I found the option to be called 'Enable native code debugging'

Comment: ...yes, that's what my VS 2017 Pro has -- no "Enable unman code deb."

Comment: Similarly, if you have a C# DLL to debug in native c++ project, choose 'Debugger type = mixed' in Debugging section of native c++ project. This will allow to step into cli/clr and c# code.

Comment: Does anybody know how to configure this for a .NET Core app in VSCode?

Answer (score 22):

To debug a C++ from C# there a couple of things you have to do.

1. Add a C# project to you solution for your debug application.
2. Edit the properties of the C# project to "Allow unmanaged code debugging" on the "Debug" tab of the project properties.
3. Set the C++ project as a dependency of the C# project.
4. Write code in your C# project to use the DLL either using P/Invoke or COM.
5. Set some breakpoints in your C++ code and run the C# project.

Answer (score 7):

I overcame this in Visual Studio 2019 by selecting "Enable native code debugging" as shown under my C# project's properies.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio cannot execute a dll on its own.

You need to set the startup .exe that will be using your C++ dll in the properties of your dll project. You can do so from **properties --> debugging --> command** specifying the path of the executable that's gonna call your dll and any command line argument needed.

Answer (score 1):

For VS 2017 Pro, go to the property page of the main project (your c# project in the solution) by right mouse clicking it.  At the Debug menu item, find the option in Debugger engines, choose Enable native code debugging.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the useful answers by [heavyd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063399/4669135) and [CCicotta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063129/4669135) and [Noobie3001](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62773507/4669135), in Visual Studio 2017 I also had to change the following when attaching to a running C# process calling a C++ DLL: in *Debug* > *Attach to process ...*, ensure **Native code** is listed by *Attach to:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> SOS (Son of Strike) Debugging Extension (SOS.dll) helps you debug
>   managed code in Visual Studio by providing information about the
>   internal CLR environment

*refer the below article:-*

[MSDN ARTICLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The option "Allow unmanaged code debugging" in the "Debug" tab works for most people, but it doesn't work for me. I have to manually select "Native" as the following to debug c++ dll in my c# code.
FYI: I'm using vs2019, and the dll is written with c++ and loaded into C# app with "dllimport".

[image]