# How to attach sources to referenced assembly in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, navigation

I am fairly new to Visual Studio, coming from Java development on Eclipse. Among other things I sorely miss from Eclipse is an ability to view source of binary assemblies.

In Eclipse I can attach reference to source code for a referenced jar and after that it is dead easy to navigate to the source, add breakpoints and debug those as though I have the libraries in my workspace.

Up to this point I have not managed to attach source code to an assembly reference.

Is it possible? How do I go about doing that (given that I do have access to the source code for this library)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using VS2010 - you will first need to compile your referenced assemblies with debug symbols.

A couple of options are then:

1. Find an object which you want to debug in Object Browser.  Right click -> Navigate To -> Sources From Symbol Files.
2. Step through your code until you step into the referenced assembly.  At this point a dialog will pop up asking where the source files are.  If it doesn't, or you cancelled it, then a "Browse to Find Source" will appear on the right.  If this is greyed out, then that may be because you are referencing a release assembly.

Comment: I don't see Sources From Symbol Files.  I believe it's a Resharper feature.

Answer (score 5):

> If you use [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), you can enable it by going to ReSharper / Options / External Sources, and move up "Sources from symbol files". Then in the tab "Sources from symbol files", click "Advanced" and there you can map source folders.

This is a copy of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620279/visual-studio-attach-source-code-to-reference), but I wanted to include it here so if you, the reader, have stumbled upon this link you have the answer too.

Comment: What means _source_ and _target_ folder in that ReSharper configuration?.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way:
If you have source code to these assemblies. Add that source code as a new project to your current solution so that the assembly project and your referencing project are part of single solution.

Now add reference to assembles in assembly project from **Add reference** and select **'Projects'** tab.

Put breakpoints in your assembly source code, and start debugging and have fun!.

Use 'step into' or F11 and breakpoints will be hit when referenced in source code.

Comment: Thanks, but this will not do.

I still need to define my dependency from the binary assembly, not the source code (I've pulled in the depencency with NuGet package manager). The fact that I have the source should only serve as a help for my debugging and code archaeology needs...

Comment: Furthermore - I use CI server to build my solution and having source projects for most external dependencies is going to needlessly grow build times for my solution.