# How to set up ReSharper to allow you to navigate to third-party DLL files and view source lines of code?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

This confusing feature in [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) claims to let you browse external sources from within Visual Studio, see *[External Sources](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Tools__External_Sources.html)* (ReSharper Web Help).

But, I don't understand what values to set for the folder substitution option. (Resharper - Options - External Sources - Advanced)

When I try navigating to source, I keep getting the message:

> PdbNavigator: No sources found in debugging information for in assembly

(This is almost a duplicate of Stack Overflow question *[Visual Studio - Attach source code to reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620279/visual-studio-attach-source-code-to-reference)*, but that post did not explain HOW to attach external sources.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is tricky, and I finally figured it out:

1. Click "Show current path settings and PDB files binding" and look at where the PDB points to for source.
2. Add a folder substitution where the source code is where the PDB says the source code is (probably a path not on your computer, but on the system that compiled the DLL file and PDB). Set the target to the source you downloaded.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: "Show current path settings and PDB files binding" is no longer where it used to be (as of the current ReSharper version).  You now have to click on the "Show Support Information" link at the bottom of the External Sources page and search through it for the original file paths.

Comment: But where is the PDB-file saying that the source is? When debugging the application, I can step into a function and will navigate to the correct file, but when navigating with Resharper, I only land at the decompiled source, although the right source is even in the same solution!