# Navigating to actual source with Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

In Visual Studio, when I ctrl-click (or ctrl-b) on a symbol from an external project, Resharper takes me to the decompiled view of the source.

I have a copy of the actual source on my computer in a different folder. How can I tell Resharper the location of this code so that I can navigate to it directly, rather than decompiled source?

Also, how can I make sure that I can step into this external code, rather than stepping over it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ReSharper Options, navigate to the *External Sources* tab and click the *Advanced...* button. This lets you create mappings to folders where your sources actually are.

Comment: I don't understand how this helps me. All I can do is specify a 'source' and a 'target', but what do I set as the source folder? The folder that Resharper caches the decompiled code in? Isn't that a bit weird?

Comment: @cbp 'Source' is the directory code was in when binaries were compiled.  Target is where source is now.

Comment: This **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223893/how-to-set-up-resharper-to-allow-you-to-navigate-to-third-party-dll-files-and-vi)** explains it in detail.