# Navigate to sources part of other solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, code-navigation

When using a local NuGet repository is it possible to set up Visual Studio so that when trying to navigate to implementation of some symbol which is part of a local NuGet dependency it would open the actual source code of it (instead of just decompiled source)?

I have the sources for dependent NuGet projects cloned locally into the same folder. Preferably I'd like a solution that does not involve creating a global solution that includes all the projects.

Comment: I don't know about Nuget, but does setting up [symbol and source files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2017) in VS help you out?

Comment: @MrMoose No, that only works during debugging, not during code navigation.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you're right. Some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3817767/685760) to similar questions seem to indicate that this is possible with Resharper. I'm not sure if that is an option for you. Failing that, it seems that VS2017 now has the ability to [view decompiled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2017#view-decompiled-source-definitions-instead-of-metadata-c) source code from libraries. Also, there is a great discussion on the issue [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/326321/33922). Maybe Packet is an option?